# How can I update series of loop data that come from php?

Tags: php

I am currently doing a student management system, and I need to do a function that update student result. Since all of the result is loop from database, I am confuse on how to update the data using same loop. I want to update all the new mark(either same or updated value) into database together when I click a submit button.

I had do some study through internet, but their way was totally different with mine.
 Here are my code.

```
                  <table class="table table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Student ID</th>
                            <th>Student Name</th>
                            <th>Student Result</th>
                          </tr>
                          <?php
                                $sql="select * from class INNER JOIN enrollment ON class.class_id=enrollment.class_id INNER JOIN student ON enrollment.stud_id=student.stud_id INNER JOIN registration ON student.reg_id=registration.reg_id WHERE class.sup_id='$sup_id' and enrollment.enrollment_status='Active' ";
                                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                                $i=1;
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
                            {
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
                            ?>

                          <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $i++ ;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['stud_code']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['stud_name']; ?></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control pw" value="<?php echo $row['class_gpa']; ?>" name="studgpa" id="studgpa"></td>
                                <td><input type="hidden" name="enrollid" value="<?php echo $row['enrollment_id']; ?>"></td>
                          </tr>
                            <?php

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan='4' style="text-align:center; font-size:1.4em;">No record found!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            }
                                ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
<button type="submit" name="subbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-block addcbtn" style="background-color: #e4e4e4; "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></i>Update</button>

if(isset($_POST['subbtn']))
        {

            $gpa=$_POST['studgpa'];
            $enrollid=$_POST['enrollid'];

            $sql2="select * from class INNER JOIN enrollment ON class.class_id=enrollment.class_id INNER JOIN student ON enrollment.stud_id=student.stud_id INNER JOIN registration ON student.reg_id=registration.reg_id WHERE class.sup_id='$sup_id' and enrollment.enrollment_status='Active' ";
            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

            while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {

                mysqli_query($con,"update enrollment set class_gpa='$gpa' where enrollment_id='$enrollid");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There a trick to get all values from the form

Your HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++ ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stud_code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stud_name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control pw" value="<?php echo $row['class_gpa']; ?>" name="studgpa" id="studgpa"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="enrollid" value="<?php echo $row['enrollment_id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

It should be

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++ ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stud_code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['stud_name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control pw" value="<?php echo $row['class_gpa']; ?>" name="studgpa[<?php echo $row['stud_code']; ?>]" id="studgpa"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="enrollid[<?php echo $row['stud_code']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['enrollment_id']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

On your PHP, you can get all values in the loop using:

```
// both will be 2 dimension array
$_POST['studgpa']
$_POST['enrollid']

// For getting `studgpa` of student code `abc`
if (!empty($_POST['studgpa']) && !empty($_POST['studgpa']['abc'])) {
    $tmp_stdgpa = $_POST['studgpa']['abc'];
}
```

Same thing to enrollid. And 1 more thing, **always put PHP code above the HTML output**. Hope this helpful to you!